# Use ListView or RecyclerView in NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I am a little confused about whether to use RecyclerView or ListView in DrawerLayout.
I read [a tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html), which explains how to create a NavigationDrawer with RecyclerView.
According to google: RecyclerView is
1) a container for displaying large data sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views.
2) Uses internally a layout manager. A layout manager positions item views inside a RecyclerView and determines when to reuse item views that are no longer visible to the user. To reuse (or recycle) a view, a layout manager may ask the adapter to replace the contents of the view with a different element from the dataset.

Because there is a very small dataset (header + a short list) in Navigation Drawer and all items are still visible to user, I couldn't benefit from recycler view "features" in 1) & 2).
Even Google used [ListView in NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).
I guess I could use `ListView.addHeader()` to create a special view for header in DrawerLayout.
So my question is If I should prefer RecyclerView over ListView in DrawerLayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is good. Now answering your question , if you are planning to use an expandable list items inside your navigation drawer in future , you need to be prepared to implement expandable recyclerview(which doesn't exist by default) if you are using `RecyclerView` now. So in that case `ExpandableListView` would be an easier solution to implement. However if you don't require any expandable item features inside your drawer then it would be a better approach to use `RecyclerView` if you are using a large dataset. As you said you have a small dataset i don't think it will make much impact if you use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. Still as `RecyclerView` is more flexible why not use `RecyclerView` only.

For your requirements , i would recommend to import [android design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) so that you can use `NavigationView` which makes it easier by providing the framework you need for the navigation drawer as well as the ability to inflate your navigation items through a menu resource.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at the design support library. I am still waiting for the answer explaining my question.

Comment: I answered your question too. What specific question you are still having?

Comment: OK, I was expecting a clear explanation like: "You should use ListView/RecyclerView because ...". You mentioned only "... i don't think it will make much impact if you use ListView or RecyclerView .... RecyclerView is more flexible why not use RecyclerView only." 
For me is not clear how can I benefit from the "flexibility" of RecyclerView in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Using Navigation Drawer is very complicated, Google came up with a better and easier way to implement drawers the [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog), and your list should now be a "menu", that you can define in a separate xml file, no need for Adapters anymore. For more info on how to implement it check the official android blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at the design support library, I am still waiting for the answer explaining my question.

Answer (score 2):

The same question was pinching my mind when I was developing Material design navigation drawer for my app.

Even you can see the class overview of RecyclerView which defines

> A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.

And our Navigation drawer has fixed number of items.

So, probably you will set `public void setHasFixedSize (boolean hasFixedSize)` to true. Which will make it nearly a ListView.

I use ListView in my drawer and you should also use the ListView.

Comment: Exactly I would set has fixed size to true if using the RecyclerView. I still prefer to use ListView in NavigationDrawer, because RecyclerView makes trivial things (handle clicks from Activity, adding items separator ...) too complicated and if it makes nearly no difference (comparing with ListView), I see no reason to choose RecyclerView.